# How do you display a field with an embedded quote mark in JSON-LD?

Tags: escaping, json-ld

JSON-LD fields are supposed to be double quoted

```json
"name":  "value",
```

but what if the value has an embedded double quote, like

```json
"name" : "Magnetic Strip (36" Length)"
```

Is it sufficient to escape the double quote

```json
"name" : "Magnetic Strip (36\" Length)"
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, backslashes have to be used for escaping double quotes in [string](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#dfn-string) values:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes (if necessary).

([Number](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#dfn-number), [boolean](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#dfn-true) and [null](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#dfn-null) values don’t get enclosed in double quotes, but can’t contain double quotes in the value anyway.)